# j-M-Y h:i a to mm-dd-yyyy select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im a bit trap in this date format.

I have a date format in my database "j-M-Y h:i a" = "10/15/2020 Thu 09:29:35 am"

i am  trying to convert this date to mm-dd-yyyy format so i can get the year and make a trap sql code to select only 2022 dates in my database.
LIKE THIS QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE date_received >= 2022
```

This code not work for me

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE YEAR(date_received) >= 2022
```

i also tried other conversion query but i only getting "null" or invalid syntax

Comment: try running this query and check whether it is returning year from the provided datetime field or not `SELECT YEAR(date_received) FROM document`

Comment: might be your `date_received` field is not a datetime field.

Comment: i am using varchar in my date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using varchar field for datetime values you have to convert string value to datetime using `STR_TO_DATE` function after that `YEAR` function will work becase `YEAR` function take date field or datetime field as input:

In your case like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM document 
WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE("10/15/2020 Thu 09:29:35 am", '%m/%d/%Y')) >= 2022

SELECT * 
FROM document 
WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date_received, '%m/%d/%Y')) >= 2022
```

Comment: What if the date value is "17-Aug-2020"?

Comment: then you have to change your query slightly `SELECT  YEAR(STR_TO_DATE("17-Aug-2020 Thu 09:29:35 am", '%d-%M-%Y')) FROM users `

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to cast your field as date. First trim that field. Then using date_format as '%Y", you can extract four digit year from it. If you want two digit year, you have to use '%y'.

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CAST(TRIM(date_received) AS DATE),'%Y') >= '2022';
```

Comment: What if the date value is "17-Aug-2020"?

Comment: No problem. If you want result as 17-Aug-2020, then it should be DATE_FORMAT(CAST(TRIM(date_received) AS DATE),'%d-%M-%Y'). Here %M means Jan, Feb etc. %m means 01,02 etc. %d means date part,01 to 31 as per month. If your varchar field contains 17-Aug-2020, then DATE_FORMAT(CAST(TRIM(date_received) AS DATE),'%Y') will show 2020 as output in string format.

Comment: sorry sir but the result i am getting is null.

Comment: Please show me the exact query you have written.

Answer (score 0):

If your column data type is string "17-Aug-2020" in that case you need to convert string to date and then cast in expected date format then using %Y you can get year from your string.

```
SELECT * FROM document m WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CAST(TRIM(STR_TO_DATE(date_received  ,'%d-%M-%Y')) AS DATE),'%Y') >= '2022';
```

try this example also

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(TRIM(STR_TO_DATE('May-01-2022','%M-%d-%Y')) AS DATE),'%Y')
```